# How can i access into an json without know the key?

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON like this: they are errors I need to print the error what happened error1, or error2 or error3 and so on

```
errors = {deployer: ['error1'],
 discard: ['error2'],
 worker: ['error3']
...}
```

sometimes they are only `deployer` or only `discard` or only `worker` or all or two of them, but I don't know what kind of error is going to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will map through the `erros` object keys and log the corresponding value for each key if it is not an empty array:

```js
const errors = {
  deployer: ['error1'],
  discard: ['error2'],
  worker: ['error3']
  // ...
};

for (const key in errors) {
  if (errors[key].length > 0) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${errors[key]}`);
  }
}
```

you can use `${errors[key].join(', ')}` to join all the values inside the array if they are all `string`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values()` to get all the values of the object without knowing the keys. Then, for each array in those values, you can use the spread operator to print all elements of each error array.

```
const errors = {
    deployer: ['error1'],
    discard: ['error2'],
    worker: ['error3']
};

Object.values(errors).forEach((e) => {
    console.log(...e);
});
```